# addScore method is over writing current array values instead of appending to the current list

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a novice java student.  I have a project for a java class where I am to write a Golfer class, Score class and a tester for the Golfer class to test all methods.  The specific problems I am having is :

1. When I call the addScore method, the method overwrites the old data instead of adding to the existing.  I need to get the program to add the scores in the array in addition to the previous score.
2. The findScore method is private and used in the public method getScore, however, when I run the program, I get the null value regardless of the parameter in the call.  I need to return the index of an array based on the date entered.

The following is excerpts from the code and not the entire program.

```
public class Golfer {
   /**String representing the golfer's name*/
   private String name;

   /**String representing the golf course where the golfer's hadicap is kept*/
   private String homeCourse;

   /**Unique integer that identifies every golfer*/
   private int idNum;

   /**Array storing all the golfer's scores*/
   private Score[] scores;

   public static int nextIDNum;

   /**Default constructor, sets all instance field to a default value.     Creates Array.
   */
   public Golfer() {
      name = "";
      homeCourse = "";
      scores = new Score[0];
      nextIDNum = 1000;
   }

   /**Constructor sets name and homeCourse from parameters and uses the static variable nextIDNum to retrieve the next available ID number. Creates Array.
   */
   public Golfer(String golferName, String home) {
      setName(golferName);
      setHomeCourse(home);
      setNextIDNum(nextIDNum);
      scores = new Score[10];
   }


   /**Creates a Score object from the parameters that represent the course, course rating, course slope, date and score.  Adds the newly created Score object to the Array of Scores. 
   @param golfCourse A String representing the golf course name
   @param rating A double representing the golf course rating
   @param slope An int representing the golf course slope
   @param scoreDate A String representing the date the course was played
   @param score An int representing what was scored on the course
   */
   public void addScore(String golfCourse, double rating, int slope, String scoreDate, int score) {
      Score[] golfScores = new Score[scores.length + 1];

      for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
             golfScores[i] = scores[i]; 
      }
      golfScores[golfScores.length - 1] = new Score(golfCourse, rating, slope, scoreDate, score);

      scores = golfScores;
   }

   /**Deletes a score from the Array based on score date,  Assumes only one score per day. 
   @param golfDate A string representing the date of the golf score
   @return true if score found and deleted, 
   @return false if score not found.
   */
   public boolean deleteScore (String golfDate) {

      for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
         if (findScore(golfDate) > 0) {
            scores[i] = null;
         } 
         return true;        
      }
      return false;
   }

   /**Returns a score object based on the score date. If not found returns null
   @param golfDate The date of the golf score
   @return Scores[i] The score on the parameterized date
   @return null A null value if the score was not found.
   */
   public Score getScore(String golfDate) {

      for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
         if (findScore(golfDate) > 0) {
            return scores[i];
            }  
      }
      return null;
   }

   /**Given a parameter representing the score's date, finds the score    on a given date and returns the Array index of a score. Return constant NOTFOUND if not found.
   @param golfDate A string representing the date of the score
   @return i An array index representing the score
   @return NOTFOUND A constant set to -1 if the score isn't found
   */
   private int findScore(String golfDate) {
      final int NOTFOUND = -1;

      for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

         if (scores[i].equals(golfDate)) {
            return i;
         }
      }
      return NOTFOUND;
   }

}
```

The score class:

```
public class Score {

   private String courseName;
   private int score;
   private String date;
   private double courseRating;
   private int courseSlope;


   public Score(String course, double rating, int slope, String golfDate, int scr) {
      setCourseName(course);
      setScore(scr);
      setDate(golfDate);
      setCourseRating(rating);
      setCourseSlope(slope);
   }


   public Score() {
      courseName = "";
      score = 0;
      date = "";
      courseRating = 0.0;
      courseSlope = 0;
   }


   public void setCourseName(String course) {
      courseName = course;
   }


   public String getCourseName() {
      return courseName;
   }


   public void setScore(int golfScore) {
      if ((golfScore < 40) && (golfScore > 200)) {
         golfScore = 9999;
         System.out.println("Error: golf score must be between 40 and 200.");
         }
            score = golfScore;
   }


   public int getScore() {
      return score;
   }


   public void setDate(String golfDate) {

      date = golfDate;
   }


   public String getDate() {
      return date;
   }


   public void setCourseRating(double rating) {
      if ((rating < 60) && (rating > 80)) {
         rating = 9999;
         System.out.println("Error: the course rating must be between 60 and 80.");
         }
            courseRating = rating;

   }


   public double getCourseRating() {
      return courseRating;
   }


   public void setCourseSlope(int slope) {
      if ((slope < 55) && (slope > 155)) {
         slope = 9999;
         System.out.println("Error: The course slope must be between 55 and 155.");
         }
            courseSlope = slope;

   }



}
```

The tester class:

```
public class GolferTester {

   public static void main (String []args) {
      String course1 = "Augusta National";
      String course2 = "Bayhill CC";
      String course3 = "TPC Sawgrass";

      String player1 = "Sam Snead";
      String player2 = "Arnold Palmer";
      String player3 = "Jack Nicklaus";

      int score1  = 66;
      int score2  = 201;
      int score3  = 72;

      int slope1  = 60;
      int slope2  = 156;
      int slope3  = 77;

      double rating1 = 65.2;
      double rating2 = 81.8;
      double rating3 = 70.9;

      String date1 = "01/01/2017";
      String date2 = "06/01/2016";
      String date3 = "12/22/2016";

      Golfer golfer1    = new Golfer(player1, course1);
      Golfer golfer2    = new Golfer(player2, course2);

      Score s1 = new Score(course1, rating1, slope1, date1, score1);
      Score s2 = new Score(course2, rating2, slope2, date2, score2);

      s1.setScore(score1);
      s1.setDate(date1);
      s1.setCourseRating(rating1);
      s1.setCourseSlope(slope1);
      s1.setCourseName(course1);

      s2.setScore(score3);
      s2.setDate(date3);
      s2.setCourseRating(rating3);
      s2.setCourseSlope(slope3);
      s2.setCourseName(course3);

      golfer1.addScore(s1.getCourseName(), s1.getCourseRating(), s1.getCourseSlope(), s1.getDate(), s1.getScore());
      golfer2.addScore(s2.getCourseName(), s2.getCourseRating(), s2.getCourseSlope(), s2.getDate(), s2.getScore());

      System.out.println(golfer1);
      System.out.println("");      
      System.out.println(golfer2);
      System.out.println("");

      s1.setScore(score2);
      s1.setCourseRating(rating2);
      s1.setCourseSlope(slope2);

      golfer1.addScore(s1.getCourseName(), s1.getCourseRating(), s1.getCourseSlope(), s1.getDate(), s1.getScore());     

      System.out.println(golfer1);

      deleteScore(s1.getDate());

      System.out.println(s1.getDate());
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreacited

Comment: Why using an array and not a list?

Comment: I haven't been introduced to array lists as of yet.  I suppose I'll read up on them and try to alter what I have.

Comment: After reviewing the instructions, we aren't able to use array lists, only arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use an array for a list of elements that you know will grow/shrink. Use ArrayList, which has add()
2. Your getScore method is returning null always

Comment: To give OP more information on point 1, an array cannot change size at runtime without being instantiated as a new array. Objects implementing the `List` interface, such as `ArrayList` can grow/shrink in size arbitrarily

Comment: @j.seashell +1, and to add on to that: an array can **not** change size after it has been created, however you *can* reassign the reference variable "scores" to a **new** array of a different size. Also, every java collection has the ability to expand or decrease in size, not just implementations of List

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with array lists, haven't made it that far yet.

Comment: After reviewing the instructions, an array is the only collection object allowed.

Comment: Ok, then you can use the same technique that ArrayList uses behind the scenes: whenever you need to add more elements to your array, create a new array with a larger capacity via Arrays.copyOf(). You will then have a larger array which can hold your new values, while preserving the previous values. See add() and ensureCapacity() in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java